# Search Most Word from a Column in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, text, cpu-word

I have a table named 'tweet' and its column 'text'. The column contains a sentence (many words) in each record. Then I wanna search the most word from the column. Is that possible to do that in MySQL query? If so, then I want to know also to add exception words like: 'a', 'I', etc...

I thought it's similar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707754/get-popular-words-in-phpmysql)
But it's using PHP.

I very appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not the obvious tool for something like this.  But, if you are going to use SQL, I would suggest that you parse the text into a `TweetWords` table, with one row per "tweet" and word in the tweet (along with position information).

If you are inserting the data through PHP, you can do the parsing there and then insert each word independently.

Then the count is easy, using a basic aggregation query.

Comment: hmm I think so. 
Actually the data is inserted. So I just need to search the most word. But anyone knows how to do this question in PHP?
anw, thanks Gordon!

Comment: also, sorry for not clear question. please let me know which part is...